# Add Eclipse default menu items in Run Menu Item

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, rcp

I have an RCP application with my own custom perspective. When I am in eclipse debug perspective I see all the options under Run Menu, but when I switch to my own perspective I see only "External Tools" under Run menu. How can I enable all the options to be available in Run menu in my custom perspective as well

Here is how it looks in Debug Perspective, I want all these options to be available in my custom perspective

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your perspective factory add the action sets defined by the debug plugin for these actions:

```
@Override
public void createInitialLayout(IPageLayout layout) {

    ...

    layout.addActionSet(IDebugUIConstants.LAUNCH_ACTION_SET);
    layout.addActionSet(IDebugUIConstants.DEBUG_ACTION_SET);
}
```

`IDebugUIConstants` is `org.eclipse.debug.ui.IDebugUIConstants` in the `org.eclipse.debug.ui` plug-in which you will need to add to your plug-ins dependencies.

If your perspective has already been opened you will need to do a perspective reset to get the new definition.

Comment: Does eclipse hide it by itself in other perspectives?

Comment: Eclipse only shows actions sets in perspectives that explicitly ask for them to be shown.